# Car starts with remote, does not start with key

Tags: starting, pontiac, ignition-key, remote-start, vibe

2007 Vibe, starts with remote start but does not start with key.  This started after replacing dead battery a few months ago.  It is as if it does recognize the is there.  Not sure what to check.

Comment: does the security light flash when you try to start it using the key?

Comment: When using the key, does the engine turn but not run? Or is it simply nothing when twisting the key to the start position? Also, is it factory remote start or aftermarket?